# How do I concat a numeric value and a string value in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I deleted a previous question because it turned out that my issue was dialectical, but I'm still having the same issue. So, I have the follow lines in my SELECT statement:

```
COUNT(*) AS "Number of Buildings",
COUNT(*)/ SUM(COUNT(*)) over ()*100 AS "Portfolio Percentage: Buildings",
```

What I would like to do is concatenate "%" to the end of the numeric result. I've tried:

```
COUNT(*)/ SUM(COUNT(*)) over ()*100 || TO_NUMBER('%') AS "Portfolio Percentage: Buildings",
```

And:

```
TO_VARCHAR(COUNT(*)/ SUM(COUNT(*)) over ()*100) || '%' AS "Portfolio Percentage: Buildings",
```

Basically, I've tried every variation of turning the number into a CHAR/VARCHAR, or turning the "%" into a number, that I can think of. They always return the same error, which is some variation of:

```
Numeric value '%' is not recognized
```

Comment: I tried: "select TO_VARCHAR(COUNT(*)/ SUM(COUNT(*)) over ()*100) || '%' AS "Portfolio Percentage: Buildings" from TBLNAME;"    that worked for me with no errors.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `TO_NUMBER('%')`.

Instead of:

```sql
select COUNT(*)/ SUM(COUNT(*)) over ()*100 || TO_NUMBER('%') AS "Portfolio Percentage: Buildings"
from (select 1)
```

do

```sql
select COUNT(*)/ SUM(COUNT(*)) over ()*100 ||'%' AS "Portfolio Percentage: Buildings"
from (select 1)
```